# Website tracking Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

Our emails contain links to external websites and I would like to capture the behavior/tracking data from those websites back into Marketing Cloud.

Reading through different posts and documentation, I figured that it can be accomplished via 2 methods -
**Google Analytics 360 (GA360) integration** .
**Web Analytics configuration** (by installing Collect Code)

I am wondering which one is recommended for what use case? Also, for Web Analytics, is Predictive Web/Email a mandatory requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Google Analytics 360 (GA360) integration is really expensive even it is comprehensive. Hence, Web Analytics configuration is more suitable for companies to choose. If you use Predictive(Einstein) Web/Email data extensions and data structure while achieving this, you can store the data in those data extensions. In other words, you can see the data not only on Web Tracking dashboard visually, also on data extensions to take actions based on those.

Comment: Thanks @Selim. Does Web Analytics also provide subscriber level data?

Comment: You can improve your collect data js to get subscriber level data. With that improvement, you can see who sees what product/page and when.